# WKWebView blurry PDF

Tags: ios, pdf, wkwebview

I'm trying to display a PDF file inside of a WKWebView but parts of the PDF file are being rendered blurry. Has anyone found a solution for this?

```
self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:webViewConfiguration];
[self.view addSubview:self.webView];

[self.webView loadData:pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" characterEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:targetURL];

self.webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.webView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
[self.webView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
[self.webView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.navBar.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
[self.webView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
```

In the attached screenshot you can see the bottom half of the PDF data is being rendered blurry.

[image: Blurry]

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem. I have it too. So frustrating. Was hoping there was a rasterise = NO option or something. But no -(

Comment: We never found a solution for this :(

Comment: We never found a solution for this :(

Comment: Hi Rob. So, I ended up dropping using a webView and instead opening the PDF using pdfView. I then added the pdfView as a subview to my view controllers view. Zooming, panning, scanning - fine. Everything scaled correctly, no blurriness. The webView would have been a better option for me as it provided page number from and to, out of the box. But the blurriness was making the whole thing unreadable.

Comment: Nice man. Unfortunately our app still has to support iOS 9. So PDFKit is not an option for us. Glad it works for you.